# Highlighted text color in Atom

Tags: css, atom-editor

I'm trying to change the font color for highlighted text in Atom, but there doesn't seem to be a way. Google seems to reveal that it is a known limitation, but i wanted to see if we could figure it out anyway.

I've tried:

```
  .selection .region {
    background-color: #a5a5a5;
    color: #FF0000;
  }
```

But it only changed the highlight background, not the text.